# How to create trigger to change status after insert and update in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, triggers, insert, insert-update

i have a table (input) with some fields :

- check_number int (primary key)
- name varchar(20)
- nominal int
- date1 date
- date2 date
- status varchar(20)

i want to make trigger with these condition :

- if i insert data in input_table then status will change into (Unpaid) automatically (which is date2 is null when i insert the data)
- if date2 is more than 1 month after date1 (and it's count from date system) then status will change into (Expired). for this case, i'm not inserting or updating, it's automatically take from system date
- if date2 is in range 1 month between date1 and date2, status will change (Paid)

for example :

- date1 = 12-02-2015, date2 = null, status = Unpaid
- date1 = 12-02-2015, date2 = 26-02-2-15, status = Paid
- date1 = 12-02-2015, date2 = 12-03-2015 (date now without insert or update), status = Expired

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to cover all your requirements with triggers.

What you can do and better be doing anyway is calculating `status` on the fly or using the same conditions in `WHERE` clause if you're fetching rows for of a specific status

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN date2 IS NULL AND 
                 date1 >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN 'Unpaid'
            WHEN date2 <= date1 + INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN 'Paid'
            WHEN date2 IS NULL AND
                 date1 < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH THEN 'Expired' END status
  FROM input_table t
```

Sample output:

```
| CHECK_NUMBER | NAME | NOMINAL |             DATE1 |             DATE2 |  STATUS |
|--------------|------|---------|-------------------|-------------------|---------|
|            1 | John |       1 | February, 16 2015 |            (null) |  Unpaid |
|            2 | Jane |       1 | February, 03 2015 | February, 17 2015 |    Paid |
|            3 | Mark |       1 |  January, 16 2015 |            (null) | Expired |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94e4a/1)** demo

Comment: yes, you're right about the sample output :) so i should write that code on my query in PHP to show the status ? am i wrong ? can't i using 2 triggers which one i after insert and one is after update ? before that, thank you for your answer. i'll try :)